# Playing MP3 file from SD card in background of Android app

Tags: android

I have got some code which displays a listview of audio files in SD card and plays them. But when I move to other screens, it automatically stops. I want it to be able to play the files while using the other functions of the app.

Answer (score 0):

use AsyncTask ( or any sub-class in that constructor chain ) and as well consider Service but best case is to do AsyncTask and remember you have to start the thread yourself- just like is says in the docs for that

Answer (score 0):

If you want your **media to play in the background even when your application is not onscreen**—that is, you want it to continue playing while the user is interacting with other applications—then you must start a Service and control the MediaPlayer instance from there.

Please refer this link its nice example for [Android Music Player](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/musicdroid-audio-player-part-i).